# Allow new tiles to be loaded while dragging map

Tags: openlayers

At least by default (for example with [the OL3 examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/accessible.html)), new titles are not loaded while the map is being dragged. A blank area is shown where tiles have not loaded yet. When the dragging stops, the tiles are loaded and the blank areas fill in.

How can I configure Openlayers3 to allow new tiles to be loaded while dragging the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two related settings on ol.Map (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html)

- loadTilesWhileInteracting
- loadTilesWhileAnimating

Both of which default to false. Set to true.

> **`loadTilesWhileAnimating` | boolean | undefined | experimental**
>   When set to true, tiles will be loaded during animations. This may improve the user experience, but can also make animations stutter on devices with slow memory. Default is false.
>
> **`loadTilesWhileInteracting` | boolean | undefined   | experimental**
>   When set to true, tiles will be loaded while interacting with the map. This may improve the user experience, but can also make map panning and zooming choppy on devices with slow memory. Default is false.

Comment: Okay I expanded a bit. Out of interest, is the flagging done automatically based on number of characters? Or something manual?

Comment: I for one thought it was plenty. I didn't think to look in the "map" object for such options, only in the layers themselves. Thanks!